# Ninject and Request Scope For Connection

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, database-connection, ninject

Will request scope tied to my DatabaseFactory release my database connection after the request is finished?

```
kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory<MySqlConnection>>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", Config.Data.MySQLConnection);


public class DatabaseFactory<T> : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory where T : IDbConnection, new()
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private  IDbConnection _dataConnection;

        public DatabaseFactory(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        #region IDatabaseFactory Members

        public IDbConnection Get()
        {
            return _dataConnection ?? (_dataConnection = new T { ConnectionString = _connectionString });
        }

        #endregion

        protected override void DisposeCore()
        {
            if (_dataConnection != null)
                _dataConnection.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Ninject.Web.MVC](http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html) extension then those objects are guaranteed to be disposed once the request object is collected by the Garbage Collector (GC) (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145775/ninject-doesnt-call-dispose-on-objects-when-out-of-scope))

Comment: It seems from that post by using InRequestScope, it disposes the DBFactory at the end of the request.  Am I wrong in noticing that in the post you sent?