# Can't get Ninject to dispose object in Request Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I can't seem to get Ninject to dispose objects in request scope in an ASP.NET MVC application with web API no matter what I do.

What I am doing:

- Create a new ASP.NET Web Application with Visual Studio 2013. I select the MVC template and add a Web API to it (it also has ASP.NET Identity in the package by default)
- I install Ninject.MVC5 package via nuget (install-package Ninject.MVC5)
- I add a the following class to my application:

  public class SomeDisposable : IDisposable
  {
      public void Dispose()
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
      }
  }
- I add the following binding in NinjectWebCommon RegisterServices method

  kernel.Bind().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
- I add an object of the type SomeDisposable to the Home controller

  public HomeController(SomeDisposable some)
  {
  }
- I run the application and place a breakpoint in the HomeController constructor and the Dispose method of the SomeDisposable class. The controller receives an object (presumably from Ninject), the page loads but **the Dispose method is never called**.
- At this point things are already broken but I add a Web API controller, install Ninject.WebApi packaged and repeat the experiment with the WebAPI controller and I get the same result.

I have read a bunch of questions including this one - [Ninject doesn't call Dispose on objects when out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145775/ninject-doesnt-call-dispose-on-objects-when-out-of-scope) and the Ninject documentation https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope and they both indicate that due to the fact that Ninject.Web.Common includes a registration for the OnePerRequestHttpModule (yes it is there) the disposal should just work but it doesn't. I also tried adding the PerRequest module in the web.config and got an error saying that I can't have this section in integrated mode.

At this point I am lost. I suspect either integrated mode or OWIN have something to do with this but I have no idea how to debug it or what to do to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This happened to me a while ago, make sure that you have all of the latest versions of Ninject's dependencies.  The one that provides functionality for determining request scope has a bug that holds onto the objects much longer than needed and is fixed in a later version.  Apologies for being vague, I can't remember the relevant names/versions.

Comment: Some people also reported issues with updating - whereas after updating `.InRequestScope()` didn't work anymore, at all. AFAIR Removing and reinstalling all packages in the right sequence was the key.. but don't ask me which sequence ;o

Comment: I find it absurd that I can't get it to work on an empty project without changing anything from the default configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object not being disposed was a problem in `Ninject.Web.Common` before version 3.2.2, as discussed here: [InRequestScope is failing to dispose objects](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/132#issuecomment-42459686)

As you have been installing Ninject via nuget, you probably installed the oldest supported dependencies. This can be avoided by using:

```
Install-Packages Ninject.MVC5 -DependencyVersion Highest
```

Please verify that you are using the current version of all Ninject packages.

Comment: That did work (I used update rather than install fresh package). Do you happen to know the reasoning behind installing the oldest dependencies instead of the newest non-beta ones?

Comment: @Stilgar There is a discussion thread about this "feature": https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/436712

Comment: I had been using 3.0.0.7 from March 2012, I wonder if this exhibited the issue--I don't *think* it did because I have a RavenDB session bound to InRequestScope and it surely would have barked at me for exceeding the 30 req/session default limit. I came here looking for another issue thinking this might be it. Even if it's not, good to know about this!

Comment: I have this issue, and I have version 3.3.1
It, however, does dispose some of the time, and some of the time it does not.

I added a console output on the constructor and a console output on the dispose,
and although the dispose does get exectued some of the time, it also does not execute all the time. any thoughts?